# Blag Fog/Obsure/Darken Character Face

Tags: modeling, particles, unity, effects

Making a videogame in unity! Till the end of the game the player can't see the protagonist's face (the game is 3d from the top), he wears a hoodie and a mantel that cover most of his body all the time and when you try to zoom in inside the hoodie there is a blag fog or something alike that won't let you. How do I do this :P?[image]

Comment: Hello ! One solution is to create a plane or a series of parallel planes starting at the hoodie entrance, give them a spearate material and control the opacity and color directly in your game engine. Thing is you can do it in Blender but you'll have trouble exporting the effect in another software

Comment: wow so quick! thank you for answering. If you say so then I think I'll just directly do this effect in unity with the particle system. I just wanted to see if it was possible to make the effect a part of the model itself